# to display all records using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I have written code for displaying records on that same page but its not working.Actually I want in page which I insert that same page should show all records in table format and also show recently added record without refreshing page.

ajaxinsert.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#insert").click(function() {
       var name  = $("#name").val();
       var rno  = $("#rno").val();
    var address = $("#address").val();

    //var dataString = "&name="+name"+&address="+address;
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      data:{name: name,
            rno:rno,
            address:address},
      url:'demo_insert.php',
      success:function(data){
       if(data="inserted") {
          alert("Insertion Success");
        } else {
          alert("Not Inserted"); 
        }
     } 
   });  
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="myform" action="demo_insert.php"> 
<label>Name: </label> <input id="name" type="text" />
<label>Rno: </label> <input id="rno" type="text" />
<label>Address: </label> <input id="address" type="text" />
<input name="Submit" type="button"  id="insert" value="Submit"/>
<!--<a id="insert" title="Insert Data" href="#">Push into mysql</a>-->
 <!-- For displaying a message -->

<div id="message"></div>
</form>
</body>
```

demo_insert.php

```
<?
    include('connection.php');
 //Pull data from home.php front-end page

 $name=mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
 $rno=mysql_escape_string($_POST['rno']);
 $address=mysql_escape_string($_POST['address']);
 //Insert Data into mysql
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO school(name,rno,address) VALUES('$name','$rno','$address')");

$dispquery=mysql_query("select * from school"); 
echo "<table border=1>";

   echo "<tr>";
   echo"<td>Srno</td>";
   echo "<td>Name</td>";
   echo"<td>Rno</td>";
   echo "<td>Address</td>";  
   echo"</tr>";
$i=1;
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($dispquery))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$i."</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$result['name'] ."</td>";
     echo "<td>" .$result['rno'] ."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" .$result['address'] ."</td>";   
    echo "</tr>";
    $i++;
}
   echo"</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, please use mysqli or PDO to connect to database, mysql methods are deprecated and will stop working sometime soon and break all your code.

Secondly, you are almost all the way there, though not quite. I suggest taking a slightly different approach, and perhaps make use of your jQuery and JSON.

Change the first file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data: {
                name: $("#name").val(),
                rno: $("#rno").val(),
                address: $("#address").val()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            url:'demo_insert.php',
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.insert) {
                    alert("Insertion Success");
                    // All your content will be in data.output now which you can append wherever
                } else {
                    alert("Not Inserted"); 
                }
            } 
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

And your php as such, please note I am not changing your code to PDO or mysqli, but you should look into that!

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
//Pull data from home.php front-end page

$response = new StdClass();

$name=mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$rno=mysql_escape_string($_POST['rno']);
$address=mysql_escape_string($_POST['address']);

//Insert Data into mysql
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO school(name,rno,address) VALUES('$name','$rno','$address')");

// Add the insert to the response
$response->insert = !$query ? false : true;

// Only continue if its true
if ($response->insert) {
$dispquery=mysql_query("select * from school");
    $response->output = '';
    $response->output .= "
        <table border=1>
        <tr>
        <td>Srno</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Rno</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        </tr>";
    $i=1;

    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($dispquery)) {
        $response->output .= "
        <tr>
        <td>$i</td>
        <td>{$result['name']}</td>
        <td>{$result['rno']}</td>
        <td>{$result['address']}</td>
        </tr>";
        $i++;
    }
    $response->output .= "</table>";
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually add the content to the DOM. In the callback function of your Ajax call, you'll get data that you can use to populate your table using functions like [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/). To see what your Ajax call is getting back from your PHP script, put `console.log(data)` in the callback, then you can use that to figure out exactly how you want to go about generating your content.

Also, the PHP `mysql` extension is deprecated. Please replace it with [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is incompatible with what you are returning.  You are responding with an html table and in your success callback treating it a simple variable.

```
success:function(data){
       if(data="inserted") {
          alert("Insertion Success");
        } else {
          alert("Not Inserted"); 
        }
     }
```

You want to either append `data` to your DOM or do something else with it.  Based on your php, you want to append it somewhere.

Comment: Even if it were JSON his `if` statement wouldn't be compatible >.>

Answer (score 0):

Few things, generalized answer to a few issues i see

Typically, if you are following some kind of MVC structure of php coding , you will want to separate your Read query logic from your Update , Insert logic and so on

So, on your php if you encapsulate your insert in a function or separate page, you can return a boolean if insert was successful, then call your read table query via another ajax getJson in the success function

In php you typically want to return your query result set 
      echo json_encode($results)

you then in your javascript, once the ajax is done() (the newest jquery method for handling ajax json successes) or success() , you can use an $.each to iterate through the result set

If your interested i can give more code examples